# What does "scratch the last question" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

It's the phrase from Friends. This is a dialog between Ross and Benhamin. Here is a part of it:

Ross: What? Wait, wait, wait, just a minute. None of my questions have anything to do with Paleontology.

Benjamin: You're right, I apologize. Scratch the last question. Spell "Boscodictiasaur".

Comment: [**scratch**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scratch) *to decide not to do something you had planned to do*.

Answer (score 3):

It is one of various informal ways of saying *erase*. Another, more common in Britain, might be *scrub the last question*.